# Using GNU Radio to perform EVM measurements

Tags: demodulation, gnuradio, qpsk

Is there any previous work describing the implementation of an **Error Vector Magnitude (EVM) measurement** system using **GNU Radio**?

The system in question is made of an SDR HW platform, e.g. USRP, providing digital I/Q signals, used as a source in GNU Radio sketch. The sketch goal shall be to decode symbols of a given modulation scheme, e.g. QPSK, synchronize to a known PRBS data sequence, e.g. PRBS13, and perform an EVM measurement.

Thanks